# Firefox - session storage purged once user moved back to firefox home tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history, session-storage

As I mentioned in the title, I have a problem with session storage, it's cleared when user switches back to home tab and then forward to my page again in firefox browser.

Steps to reproduce my issue:

1. User open a new **HOME** tab in firefox.
2. He/she visits my app -> app stores some data in session storage
3. He/she clicks move back button. -> user again is on the home tab.
4. He/she clicks move forward -> again user visits my app.
   At this point, session storage is empty (checked it through developer tool and from javascript code)

My problem happens only on windows 10 machines with firefox version 78.15.0esr.
When I change 'open a new tab as' option in firefox from Home Tab to Blank Tab, session storage is not wiped and I have an access to my data.

I've checked the same flow on different browsers, system(ubuntu) and machines and it was the same - problem was only on windows 10 using firefox.

As a side note, I cannot use local storage since I need to handle users sessions per different tabs.

My question is what will be the best solution for it?
should I somehow detect that user is trying to access firefox home tab and prevent it?

EDIT: Just to prove that my app does not make any issues, I've checked it directly from the browser console and the result is the same. Looks like it's probably a firefox bug. But my question is still active since my app requires to be fully compatible.

Thanks